# Get Info about several files in 1 request

Tags: ios, box-api

I have a bunch of files downloaded for offline viewing from Box together with their IDs/modifiedAt.

I want to check them all for updated modifiedAt.
I am currently using files/FILE_ID (http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-get), but then I need to send a request for each file.

Is there any way to get file info in bulk, many files at once?
(I am using the iOS SDK)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The API currently does not support bulk operations, unfortunately, though it's something we're considering.

Comment: Ok, that would be good. Do you know how the ios Box app does it? It has a "Updates" tab.

Comment: You could use the /events endpoint to get notifications of all the files that have been updated.

Comment: Is this the intended use of /events or is it a workaround? Does the box app use use /events? /events are not included in the ios sdk I think.